# SQL Joins ADODB

Tags: sql, join, adodb

I have two tables, Internal and External.
Both tables have same columns viz. Title, Name, Address, Id, RefNo, MergeRefNo, Status

Assume the 'External' table has data below:

```html
<table style="width: 351px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 38px;">Title</td>
      <td style="width: 43px;">Name</td>
      <td style="width: 59px;">Address</td>
      <td style="width: 25px;">Id</td>
      <td style="width: 52px;">RefNo</td>
      <td style="width: 86px;">MergeRefNo</td>
      <td style="width: 47px;">Status</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 38px;">Mr.</td>
      <td style="width: 43px;">White</td>
      <td style="width: 59px;">123</td>
      <td style="width: 25px;">D1</td>
      <td style="width: 52px;">100_A</td>
      <td style="width: 86px;">NULL</td>
      <td style="width: 47px;">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 38px;">Ms.</td>
      <td style="width: 43px;">Rita</td>
      <td style="width: 59px;">234</td>
      <td style="width: 25px;">D2</td>
      <td style="width: 52px;">100_B&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 86px;">NULL&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 47px;">A&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 38px;">Dr.</td>
      <td style="width: 43px;">CP</td>
      <td style="width: 59px;">678</td>
      <td style="width: 25px;">D3</td>
      <td style="width: 52px;">100_C</td>
      <td style="width: 86px;">100_B</td>
      <td style="width: 47px;">M&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the 'Internal' table has data as below:

```html
<table style="width: 351px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 38px;">Title</td>
      <td style="width: 43px;">Name</td>
      <td style="width: 59px;">Address</td>
      <td style="width: 25px;">Id</td>
      <td style="width: 52px;">RefNo</td>
      <td style="width: 86px;">MergeRefNo</td>
      <td style="width: 47px;">Status</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 38px;">Mr.</td>
      <td style="width: 43px;">John</td>
      <td style="width: 59px;">XYZ</td>
      <td style="width: 25px;">D1</td>
      <td style="width: 52px;">100_A</td>
      <td style="width: 86px;">NULL</td>
      <td style="width: 47px;">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 38px;">Ms.</td>
      <td style="width: 43px;">Blue</td>
      <td style="width: 59px;">CDE</td>
      <td style="width: 25px;">M6</td>
      <td style="width: 52px;">100_B&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 86px;">NULL&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 47px;">A&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 38px;">Dr.</td>
      <td style="width: 43px;">CP</td>
      <td style="width: 59px;">678</td>
      <td style="width: 25px;">D3</td>
      <td style="width: 52px;">100_C</td>
      <td style="width: 86px;">100_B</td>
      <td style="width: 47px;">M&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The requirement is, where IDs are same in both tables and status is 'A' (or) RefNos are same and Status in ('A','M'), data in 'Internal' should overwrite 'External'.

So, in above example, since both D1 is common in both tables, 'White' should be replaced with 'John'. Also, 'Rita' should be overwritten with 'Blue' since Refnos are equal (i.e. 100_B, though IDs differ)

So I wrote the below query

```
select   isnull(c.title,isnull(b.title,a.title)),isnull(c.initials,isnull(b.initials,a.initials)),isnull(c.forename,isnull(b.forename,a.forename)),isnull(c.surname,isnull(b.surname,a.surname)),isnull(c.id,isnull(b.id,a.id)) 
from  external a
left  join internal b on a.id = b.id -- and status = 'a' -- unable to use this in ADO
left join internal c on c.refno= a.refno  -- and status in ('a','m') -- unable to use this in ADO
```

but when there is value in 'external' (e.g. XYZ)  which needs to be replaced with 'null' data in Internal, the above query fails, because of IsNull. How could I actually use the 'Internal' table values which satisfy both join conditions (i.e. IDs are same (or) Refnos are same).

(Apologies for poor formatting)

(As mentioned in query, unable to use the filter in join condition in ADODB.. any clues?)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by splitting the two queries and joining them using UNION.

```
select a.title, a.initials, a.forename, a.surname, a.id
from internal a
inner join external b on a.id = b.id
where a.status = 'a'
union
select a.title, a.initials, a.forename, a.surname, a.id
from internal a
inner join external b on a.refno = b.refno
where a.status in ('a','m')
```

It works as expected, however, in case there are better options, kindly let me know.

Thanks